# Moving to trash takes too long - emptying trash takes more than 10 minutes (even for a single item)

Tags: finder, launchd, trash, ventura

OSX Ventura 13.2.1
How to recreate:
Drag folder to the trash; right click on trash and choose empty trash. Will take at least 10 minutes to empty the trash with just a single .png file.

Things I've tried:

- Disabling all `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`
- Starting up in safe mode
- Disabling all login items
- Disk utility repair
- Looking through console error messages
- Deleting via command line
- Disabling iCloud

However:
Creating a new administrator level user and logging on as them works fine within their profile